Google Speech to Text and Translation (live stream)
I have a use case where I will record a speech in live stream, and I want to have the text transcription of the audio, and then the translation of this transcription, all in real-time.
Do I need to use the Speech to Text API of Google and then send the generated text to the Translation API or can I do it in one row ?

Hi , I have posted an answer, if you find it helpful, please do consider upvoting and accepting it as per stackoverflow guidelines helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer

you can consider using a combination of the Cloud Speech-to-Text and Cloud Translation API. You can use speech to text api to Transcribe audio from streaming input into text and then we can use translation API  to convert text into the targeted language.Follow this two blog to deploy and get an idea Live Translation Using GCP
Another way it can be possible using Pub/Sub ,first using text to speech client library you can transcribe the text and publish on Pub/Sub and then those published messages through topic id , you can translate  it using translation API .  To deploy you can take a look at this  Build a Serverless Transcriber-Translator on GCP .

Yes, combine STT, TTT and TTS together. That's all you need.
In this blog I shared how I did that with FreeSWITCH and GCP:
https://dataandsignal.com/blog/static/real_time_voice_ai_speech_translation
